# Distribution of a maximum

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Randomly select $n$ numbers from ${\{1,2,\dots,m\}}$ without replacement, and order the chosen elements increasingly: $X_1 < X_2 < \dots < X_n$

And we can view each $X_i$ as a random variable, and we can get $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \frac{(m+1)i}{n+1}$

And we can define $Y_i=|X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i)|$ which is the distance of each variable to its corresponding expectation.

And we can also define $Z = \max_{1 \le i \le n} Y_i$

So what is the distribution of $Z$?

[Updated]

Any bound of $Z$ is helpful.

[Updated]
I have re-posted the question at Mathoverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78822/distribution-of-a-maximum

People there gave some new ideas.

Comment: @MartinSleziak This is the problem I think is interesting.

Comment: Is the choice of numbers done with replacement or without?

Comment: You haven't said what the distribution of the original randomly selected numbers is.  Often people say "randomly" when they mean "uniformly distributed", but I think that's on the sloppy side; I don't know that I've ever seen a probabilist or statistician do that.  Whether this is with or without replacement should also be made explicit.

Comment: I have updated that the selection is without replacement.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor withou replacement.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've been guilty of using "randomly" to mean "uniformly distributed", although generally only for uniform distributions over a finite set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer to an analogous problem. Assume the numbers are chosen independently and uniformly in the continuous interval $[0,m]$. Then, $\mathrm E(X_i)=x_i$ with $x_i=im/(n+1)$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$.

For small enough values of $z$, $[Z\leqslant z]$ is realized if and only if each interval $[x_i-z,x_i+z]$ contains exactly one value of the sample. More precisely, these intervals are disjoint for every $z\leqslant z_*=m/(2(n+1))$ and, for such values of $z$, $\mathrm P(Z\leqslant z)=n!(2z/m)^n$.

Thus, the density of the distribution of $Z$ on the interval $(0,z_*)$ is $f(z)=n!n(2/m)^nz^{n-1}$. The situation for larger values of $z$ is more complicated.

Answer (score 5):

Yours is an interesting question to ask, but hardly simple to answer. The following is *not an answer* to your question, but is given to offer certain insight into the distribution.

I ran several simulations to get an idea about distribution of $Z$. I did that for $m=100$ and $m=50$ for different values of $1 \le n < m$.

[image]

The code used to simulate histograms is as follows:

```
MathSE73091Histogram[m_Integer, n_Integer, samples_Integer, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[ListPlot]] := 
 Module[{means = (m + 1)/(n + 1) Range[n], data, omega = Range[m]},
  data = Tally[
    Table[Max@Abs[Sort[RandomSample[omega, n]] - means], {samples}]];
  data[[All, 2]] /= Total[Part[data, All, 2]];
  ListPlot[data, opts]
  ]
```

Comment: what software do you use?

Comment: @FanZhang Sorry for not mentioning this in the post. I used _Mathematica_, v8.

Answer (score 3):

This answer addresses your update "Any bound of $Z$ is helpful."  It does not give the probability distribution of $Z$.

For fixed $m$ and $n$ with $n < m$, we have $$Z \leq n \left(\frac{m+1}{n+1}-1\right),$$ and for fixed $m$, where $n$ is allowed to range over all possible values from $1$ to $m$, we have $$Z \leq \left(\sqrt{m+1}-1\right)^2.$$

---

For the first inequality, let $m$ and $n$ be fixed with $n < m$.  So $\frac{m+1}{n+1} > 1$.  Thus the maximum possible value of $\left|X_i - \frac{(m+1)i}{n+1}\right|$ occurs for one of the extreme values in an extreme *in the other direction* sample.  In other words, the largest possible value of $Z$ occurs with $Y_n$ when the sample $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is chosen or with $Y_1$ when the sample $\{m-n+1, m-n+2, \ldots, m\}$ is chosen.  By symmetry, these two values should be equal, and that is the case: In the first sample, we have $Y_n = \left|n - \frac{(m+1)n}{n+1}\right| = n \left(\frac{m+1}{n+1}-1\right)$, and in the second sample we have $Y_1 = \left|m-n+1 - \frac{m+1}{n+1}\right| = (m+1)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) - n = n \left(\frac{m+1}{n+1}-1\right).$  Thus $Z \leq n \left(\frac{m+1}{n+1}-1\right).$

To see the second inequality, just use calculus to maximize the expression $f(n) = n\left(\frac{m+1}{n+1}-1\right)$.  We get that $f(n)$ is maximized when $n = \sqrt{m+1}-1$, and thus $Z \leq \left(\sqrt{m+1}-1\right)^2$.

As an illustration of this last result, consider the numerical work posted by Sasha.  The largest values of $Z$ occur on the plots for which $n$ is closest to $\sqrt{m+1}-1$.